# How do I speed up my videos on Geforce Experience

Tags: windows-10, screen-recorder, timelapse, geforce-experience

I want to record a timelapse with GeForce experience. How would I do that? If it's not possible than what other gaming recorders can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to record a timelapse with GeForce experience, ShadowPlay should be a proper feature

NVIDIA SHADOWPLAY

RECORD AND CAPTURE YOUR GREATEST GAMING MOMENTS

https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/geforce-experience/shadowplay/

In fact, Windows 10 has built-in record video feature, press Win key + G key and you could record a game or even your screen via Windows 10 game bar.

Comment: I'm not seeing what this has to do with timelapses...